# Query string param is missed when form validation fail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an form with following url:
CreateEntity?**officeCodeId=5**

When I send form to validate and if validation is fail it returns just CreateEntity url. No officeCodeId=5.

if user click enter on URL or F5 - my site fail - it require missing officecodeId param. I can save it to the session or in the other storage. But I want to have it in the URL

My view:

```
[HttpGet]
        public virtual ActionResult CreateEntity(int? officeCodeId)
        {            
            var model = new CreateViewModel();
            FillViewModel(model, officeCodeId);
            return View("Create", model);
        }


[HttpPost]
protected virtual ActionResult CreateEntity(TEditViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              //Do some model stuff if 
            }

            return View("Create", model);
        }
```

EDIT.
My View:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEntity", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.OfficeCodeId)  
<div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, CommonRes.FirstNameCol)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, Model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, CommonRes.LastNameCol)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, Model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </div>
<div> <div class="input-file-area"></div>
                    <input id="Agreements" type="file" name="Agreements"/>
</div>
```

}

Edit 2.
Adding:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEntity", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { officeCodeId = Model.OfficeCodeId, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Haven`t help. 
It produce the following form:

```
<form action="/PhoneEmployee/CreateEntity" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" officecodeid="5">
```

### Solution Is

```
<form action="@Url.Action("CreateEntity", "Employee")?officecodeid=@Model.OfficeCodeId" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How restore query string value ?officeCodeId=5 if validation is fail.

Comment: Excellent solution!

Comment: Note to anyone else coming here and wanting to keep to using Html.BeginForm. You can add routevalues as an object before the FormMethod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `HttpPost` action doesn't have any notion of an `id` parameter. If you want to support a similar URL then make the action signature support that parameter e.g.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateEntity(int? officeCodeId)

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEntity(int officeCodeId, EditViewModel model);
```

Comment: It doesnt help. MVC still cut query string param after validation fail.

Comment: @IvanKorytin and you are posting to the same URL e.g. `CreateEntity?officeCodeId=5`? Could you perhaps show how you are posting from the view?

Comment: Thank you. I added form.

Comment: @IvanKorytin The problem is your `id` is currently part of your POST body so it won't have any effect on the URL, if you change your form code to look like `using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEntity", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { officeCodeId = "@Model.OfficeId", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` it should work.

Comment: I have some additoin code. I copied it from my real project. So yes it work. I will change it to the better undestanding.

Comment: Your solution doesn`t help. I think issue in the View("Create", Model) section.

Comment: @IvanKorytin `View(Create, Model)` does nothing but *return* a view for the page to render. It doesn't affect the URL, the URL is handled by the routing which is generally the URL you *request*. With the update you did, can you verify via a HTTP inspector (e.g. Chrome/IE Developer Tools) that you are *definitely* posting to `CreateEntity?officeCodeId=5`? It seems to me that you aren't. Remember whichever the `id` field name is in the action has to match the parameter you send up from the view otherwise they won't bind.

Comment: You are right. You can see that the solulution is work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your actions should looks like this:

Actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult CreateEntity(int? officeCodeId)
{            
    var model = new CreateViewModel();
    FillViewModel(model, officeCodeId);
    return View("Create", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult CreateEntity(ViewModel model)
{            
    if (model.IsValid) {
       // save...
       return RedirectToAction("EditEntity", newId!!!);
    } 

    return View("Create", model);
}
```

Html:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
     @Html.HiddenFieldFor(m => Model.officeCodeId)
     ...
 }
```

**Your officeId should be in model**. And on html form you can store it in hidden field.

Comment: It is the slip of the pen. The  isse is the same.

Comment: The author changed description. I've answered for the initial desc.

Comment: Yes, I did. Name convertions wasn`t important for my question.

Comment: Check the html part in the question.

Comment: "Your officeId should be in model". It is already there. The problem in url not in the model.

Comment: Looks at my action CreateEntity (post), officeid already in your model here. Why you need it in url?

Comment: If validation fail, I get url without param. User can click to this url. Url without param will create the problem becouse he can`t use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Your final answer is excellent and works great, although you can further enhance it to make it more generic by simply including `Request.QueryString`:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("CreateEntity", "Employee")?@(Request.QueryString)"
  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Then use the `POST` action:

```
[HttpPost]
protected virtual ActionResult CreateEntity(TEditViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
```