# Query string parameters get removed after do the post and return to the same page in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm implementing an asp.net mvc5 application and having an issue with post operation and query string parameters.

My page url is `http://localhost/site/person/edit?personId=20`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int personID)
{
    // ....   

    return View(person);
}
```

In this page contain submit button and it will do the post method. 
In post method, if Model.Isvalid get false, I return to the view with Model.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          //....
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "" });
    }
    else
    {
          return View(person);
    }
}
```

This works correctly.
But the issue is once the Model.IsValid get false, it will come to the view but with no query string parameters.  Then URL is like `http://localhost/site/person/edit`

Is there a way to get the URL with query string parameters.

Answer (score 9):

I found the answer on another SO post:
[Query string param is missed when form validation fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789238/query-string-param-is-missed-when-form-validation-fail)

The solution for me was to concatenate the dropped value directly onto the form tag.

Using the BeginForm() method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Person", routeValues: new {personID = Model.id}, method: FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: That's what was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Don't supply (200 OK) content in answer to a POST, but redirect with a query string to a GET method.

Supplying content in a POST is almost always a bad idea because when the user refreshes the page, the POST gets made again (along with a confusing dialog in many users agents that asks the user if they are sure the want to resend the POST)

Answer (score 1):

Add your ID to the POST method also:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int personID, Person person)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
          //....
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "" });
    }
    else
    {
          return View(person);
    }
}
```

Your view should also POST to the same URL as it is on:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Comment: If person has `personID` in it, it would be auto populated already.